# std::embed increased link time

Tags: c++, performance, file, linker

I read the proposal [P1040R4 std::embed](https://thephd.github.io/vendor/future_cxx/papers/d1040.html) and I understood that the actual problem with tools like `xxd` and `bin2c` it's that they add immense overhead when actually using the data.

This is exactly the problem that `std::embed` tries to solve when dealing with large files and my question is how much compile and link time will be affected when using this proposed feature?

Comment: Considering there isn't even a sample implementation to my knowledge, how can anyone answer this meaningfully?

Answer (score 3):

As there is no sample implementation it is impossible to tell exactly.
However, there is no reason it should be significantly slower than reading the file.

As an approximation, you can use `ld -r -b binary foo.png -o foo.o` and measure the time to link the resulting object. To access the data you would use the symbols

```
extern "C" const char foo_start;
extern "C" const char foo_end;
```

Note that `foo_start` and `foo_end` are not pointers but their adresses are at the beginning/one beyond the end of the data.

Comment: Is there any CMake macro for `ld -r -b binary` or it has to go through this way only ?

Comment: @NeelBasu I’m not certain, but I doubt it as `ld` is not cross platform.